# Why are the links and text disappearing from from this UL on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

Full disclosure, this is an assignment from an advanced JS class I'm taking.  I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of weekends and it's driving me crazy!  I'm far more familiar with jQuery than I am straight JS (which is one of the reasons I'm taking this class).

The webpage is supposed to take input from the user to create a `<UL>` list of links with some other strings associated that are related to the link.  That part works just fine, what I can't figure out is why as soon as I'm done clicking on the `Add Link` button, the new link shows very briefly, then disappears!  If I click the button very quickly, I can get several of them to show up, but as soon as I stop, all of them disappear.

I tried making a fiddle out of this, but clicking on the `Add Link` button gave me a POST error (which may be a clue to it's behavior?).  If you cut & paste the code into an HTML file & run it, you'll see the behavior I'm describing.

I thought it had something to do with the init() function, so I tried running that at the bottom of the `<body>`, but that didn't make any difference.  I also tried running it without an init, but couldn't figure out how to get the onclick listener initialized, even if it ran at the bottom of the `<body>`.  I notice that even though I'm defining the `favesList` in global scope, it's still showing up as undefined after it should have been initialized with values (at least from my point of view).  However, it looks like it's going out of scope instead which doesn't make sense to me.  Console.log isn't providing me the reason why it's disappearing, or I haven't figured out a way to log the event.

I'm reasonably certain I'm missing a fundamental thing (like it's going out of scope for some reason?), so if someone could point out what that thing is I'd be grateful (I also don't need a definitive answer, just a nudge in the right direction, this is basically homework and I know I'm supposed to be figuring this out on my own, but I think a couple of Sundays of my time is giving it the college try).

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Advanced JavaScript Project: Favorites and Tags</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica, Ariel, sans-serif;
    }
    form {
        display: table;
        border-spacing: 5px;
        width: 40%;
    }
    form p {
        display: table-row;
    }
    form label {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: right;
    }
    form input {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 95%;
    }
    span.comment {
        font-size: 80%;
        color: #777777;
    }
    span.tags {
        font-size: 80%;
        color: rgb(48, 99, 170);
    }
    #submit {
        width: 20%;
    }
  </style>
  <script>

    window.onload = init;
    var favesList;
    console.log(favesList);

    function init() {
        //get submit button handle
        var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
        //add click handler to button to call method to add text to the list
        submit.onclick = AddFavorite;
        console.log("back in init");
    }

    function favorite(url, title, comment, tags){
        console.log(this);
        this.url = url;
        this.title = title;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.tags = tags;
        console.log(this);
    }

    function AddFavorite(){
        var f = new favorite(
            document.getElementById("url").value, 
            document.getElementById("title").value, 
            document.getElementById("comment").value, 
            document.getElementById("tags").value);
        console.log(f);
        favesList = document.getElementById("list");
        console.log(favesList);
        var node = document.createElement("LI");
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(f.title));
        a.href = f.url;
        console.log(a);
        node.appendChild(a);
        node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(f.comment));
        node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(f.tags));
        console.log(node);
        favesList.appendChild(node);
        console.log(favesList);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tag and save your favorites</h1>
    <form id="form">
     <fieldset>
      <legend>Add a new favorite:</legend>
      <label for="url">URL:</label>
      <span><input id="url" type="url" placeholder="http://www.cnn.com" value="http://www.cnn.com"></span><br>
      <label for="title">Title:</label>
      <input id="title" type="text" value="CNN World News"><br>
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <input id="comment" type="textarea" value="Thoughts?"><br>
      <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
      <input id="tags" type="text" value="Enter keywords separated by commas"><br>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Add Link">
     </fieldset>
    </form>
    <br>
    <h1>List of favorites</h1>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return false;` as the last line in your `AddFavorite()` method, to stop the browser from processing the button and refreshing the page.

Comment: OK, trying not to feel too much like an ignoramus now, it's not like I didn't know that, it just never occurred to me as a solution.  That was all it took, thanks!